# Getting 'Exception:No Firebase App has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()' when refactoring my Firebase init outside of main.dart in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I have a Flutter project using Firebase and I'm trying to abstract all the Firebase usage out of UI files to a service. I initialize my Firebase in the future of `HomePage` widget below. Note that replacing the line specified in `main.dart` with the line `Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);` will resolve the issue. So why is Firebase not getting initialized when I just move this line to another file?

## `main.dart`:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: AuthService.firebase().initialize(), // THIS LINE HERE
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.done:
            final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;
            if (user != null) {
              if (user.isEmailVerified) {
                return const RecipesView();
              } else {
                return const VerifyEmailView();
              }
            } else {
              return const LoginView();
            }
          default:
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Calls out to this service, has a factory constructor for `FirebaseAuthProvider`...

## `auth_service.dart`

```
class AuthService implements AuthProvider {
  final AuthProvider provider;
  const AuthService(this.provider);

  factory AuthService.firebase() => AuthService(FirebaseAuthProvider()); // Class used in main.dart

  @override
  Future<void> initialize() => provider.initialize(); // method called in main.dart

}
```

And finally, our initialize functionality:

## `firebase_auth_provider.dart`

```
class FirebaseAuthProvider implements AuthProvider {
  @override
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  }

  @override
  AuthUser? get currentUser {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      return AuthUser.fromFirebase(user);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Full exception is here and occurs when I try to instantiate user in `main.dart` on line `final user = AuthService.firebase().currentUser;`:

```
FirebaseException ([core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp())
```

When I debug, I clearly go into the `initializeApp` method, but still get the failure on next Firebase access.
Pasting the line `Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);` into the future value in main.dart resolves the issue, but I'd like to be able to abstract the dependency out of my main.dart file. Adding `await AuthService.firebase().initialize();` to main(), before RunApp, does not resolve the issue either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add `await` keyword before `Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);` in `firebath_auth_provider.dart`... doh... resolved now.